# I want to run Docker command in jenkinsfile but I run into errors

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have three stages in jenkinsfile which are

1. Lint files
2. Variable setup
3. Build docker image.
   When I run `sh "docker build --tag=hello ."` before stage 2, the command builds the docker image but when I run the command after stage 2, Jenkins pipeline will not build the docker image and will return an error `process apparently never started in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hello@tmp/durable-b5fe7826` after about 5 minutes.

I have attached screenshots

Screenshot of the image built when I ran docker build before stage 2
[image: image built before stage 2]

Screenshot of the image failed when I ran docker build after stage 2
[image]

Here is my jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
     agent any
     stages {
          stage("Lint files") {
               steps {
                    echo "Linting HTML file..."
                    sh "tidy -q -e index.html"
                    echo "Linting Dockerfile..."
                    sh "hadolint Dockerfile"
                    sh "docker build --tag=hello1 ."
               }
          }
          stage("Variables setup") {
               steps {
                    script {
                         echo "Setting up variables for the build"
                         env.tag = readFile("./variables/tag.txt").trim()
                         env.name = readFile("./variables/name.txt").trim()
                         env.path = readFile("./variables/path.txt").trim()
                         name="${env.name}"
                         tag="${env.tag}"
                         path="${env.path}"
                         lo="name"
                    }
               }
          }
          stage("Docker image build") {
               steps {
                    echo "Hello Docker"
                    sh "docker build --tag=hello2 ."
                    echo "Hello $name"
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Here is the Docker file code

```
# hadolint ignore=DL3007
FROM nginx:latest

# Copy source code to working directory
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80
```

I have tried changing the quotes from single to double but no luck.
How can I fix this?

PS: I am running Jenkins on AWS EC2 instance

Comment: Have you [researched](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) your question?  I did a quick search and it appears to be a bug in the [Durable Task Plugin v1.25](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029374071-Build-fails-with-process-apparently-never-started-error).  Can you confirm which version of the plugin you are using on your Jenkins master?

Comment: @proxxz I read about that and updated the plugin to version 1.35 but it did not go away. I realized that jenkins change the working dir to tmp folder after the second stage but cannot find a way to prevent jenkins from changing working dir to tmp folder.

Comment: Can you include your Dockerfile too so I can reproduce the issue?  /var/lib/jenkins does look a little odd but I'm not sure how you installed Jenkins, which version you're on, or what OS you're using.  Please [provide some more details](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) so we can help.

Comment: I have edited the post to include the Dockerfile. The /var/lib/jenkins is the default path jenkins installed in because I did not alter the installation.
I installed jenkins in ubuntu 18.04 using terminal.